# indexof not working with MailApp.sendEmail

Tags: google-apps-script, indexof

I am trying to understand why the following code doesnt work:

```
function indextest() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1rMUrZFie94RLFDKaWVBPsQ-jebL8wNA6qsZWivMBDTk").getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getRange("a1:a4").getValues();
var a = data.indexOf("c");
MailApp.sendEmail ("fakeemail@gmail.com", a ,"")
}
```

I should receive an email with the text "3" in the subject line. Instead, I am receiving a "-1", implying it couldnt find "c" in the array "a1:a4". But when you go to the spreadsheet, "c" can be found in cell A3.

Here is the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rMUrZFie94RLFDKaWVBPsQ-jebL8wNA6qsZWivMBDTk/view#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

`data` looks like this `[["a"],["b"], ["c"], ["d"]]`, because Apps script gets 2d arrays regardless of width to be unambiguous, it's always an n*m matrix.

Try `indexOf(["a"])` instead.